# How to have a non-blocking indefinite loop that can be interrupted in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a process that would run indefinitely until being shut down (either from the command prompt or from another notebook cell) by changing a class member. My attempt looks like the follow:

```
def async_run(*awaitables: Awaitable,
              timeout: float = None):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    if not awaitables:
        if loop.is_running():
            return
        loop.run_forever()
        result = None
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 7):
            all_tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop)  # type: ignore
        else:
            all_tasks = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()  # type: ignore
        if all_tasks:
            # cancel pending tasks
            f = asyncio.gather(*all_tasks)
            f.cancel()
            try:
                loop.run_until_complete(f)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass
    else:
        if len(awaitables) == 1:
            future = awaitables[0]
        else:
            future = asyncio.gather(*awaitables)
        if timeout:
            future = asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout)
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(future)

        def onError(_):
            task.cancel()

        global_error_event.connect(onError)
        try:
            result = loop.run_until_complete(task)
        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            raise global_error_event.value() or e
        finally:
            global_error_event.disconnect(onError)

    return result

class Platform:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_active: bool = True

    async def kickstart(self):
        while self.is_active:
            await async_run(asyncio.sleep(0))
```

However it seems that the `kickstart()` function would simply finish running, even though my intention is for it to run indefinitely. If I remove the `async`, it does run indefinitely but then it becomes blocking. I'd appreciate some help on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible example, how to run your code and get the described problem?

Comment: Thanks @ArtiomKozyrev. Basically I'd like to know whether it is possible for an indefinite loop in one notebook cell to be interrupted by running another notebook cell (with the assumption that the former is non-blocking), I've done a fair amount of search but couldn't quite find any relevant reference. I suspect doing this in a Jupyter environment might be misguided because it is also running an event loop behind the scene so this will interfere my intended loop.

Comment: I work in Pycharm and can't answer the concrete question. But if we speak about two different processes, it is possible to stop process with e.g. http request from another one.